# How to use version control with PhpStorm

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control, phpstorm

I've just downloaded PhpStorm and I'd like to use version control, but I can't figure it out after watching countless tutorials.

I have a local project and also installed Git, and have created a repository on GitHub.

In PhpStorm my files are currently in red, if someone could please **explain in plain English** how to use VC, note that I have the latest version of PhpStorm.

Comment: Hi Seb. Do you expect a full tutorial here (which would be off-topic for this site), or do you have a **specific** question? Filenames in red in PHPStorm could indicate things not related to version control, like linting errors, but at this point it's still unclear. Please elaborate.

Comment: The red files indicated that they haven't been committed (they all became red when I installed Git, so def Git related). To pinpoint the answer, how do I commit a specific file to GitHub? and what's the practice in general with developers i.e. do you commit every file, I want to understand how I can organised my work so I can roll back any mistake.

Comment: Untracked files also show up in (brownish) red in some settings. The other questions are to be treated separately, preferably through reading a full git tutorial, I guess. Why not starting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info)?